# Overriding XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open fails in typescript

Tags: typescript, overriding

I want to override XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open in Typescript but that's failing for me, is there a workaround ?

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (method, url, async, user, pass) => {
    url = new URL(url);
    if (window["_keycloak"] && window["_keycloak"].token)
      url.searchParams.set('token', window["_keycloak"].token);
    open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

This is the error message I'm getting

> [ts] Type '(method: any, url: any, async: any, user: any, pass: any) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (method: string, url: string): void; (method: string, url: string, async: boolean, username?: string, password?: string): void; }'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to @Matt suggestion I came to find the solution.
Actually if you look at the XMLHttpRequest interface you fund two implementations for the open method

```
open(method: string, url: string): void;
open(method: string, url: string, async: boolean, username?: string | null, password?: string | null): void;
```

so the solution was to override the first one by adding optional parameters.
this is the final solution:

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (method: string, url: any , async?: boolean, username?: string, password?: string) => {
    url = new URL(url);
    if (window["_keycloak"] && window["_keycloak"].token)
    url.searchParams.set('token', window["_keycloak"].token);
    open.call(this, method, url, async, username, password);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Making async, username and password optionals solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message, the `username` and `password` parameters to the original `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` are optional (`?` mark), but in your implementation, they are required, so your implementation is not type-compatible with callers that omit those arguments.  Just mark your `user` and `pass` parameters optional.